# How can include the logout tag in my backend using FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony

Finish installing the FosUserBundle but I can not include Logout tag on my site babkend.

this is my security config

security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

```
encoders:
    "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User": plaintext
    "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
             #default_target_path: default_security_target
             #always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
            target: /
            #success_handler: persona_entity_user.component.authentication.handler.logout_success_handler                 
        anonymous:    true
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false      


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need a button or a link to fos_user_security_logout.

Something like:

```
<a href="{{ path(' fos_user_security_logout') }}" class="btn">logout</a>
```